# Redirect only specific hosts requests, leaving a default for others

Tags: linux, socat

I have a machine with only port 80 open, there is already an http server on. 
I want to intercept any incoming traffic on port 80 and:

- if coming from ip1,ip2,ip3 redirect on another application listening on another port
- Else go to the webserver

Would this be possible?Currently I am using socat but, even with reuseaddr, I still get error when starting the webserver due to port already in use...

Comment: What do you mean "with only port 80 open"? Are other ports blocked by some external firewall (e.g. a router with NAT, only port 80 is forwarded)? or by internal software firewall (`iptables` rules)?

Comment: Unfortunately the block is outside my machine so I can't do anything about that...

Answer (score 1):

You said "with only port 80 open". If other ports are blocked by some external firewall (e.g. a router with NAT, only port 80 is forwarded to you), then a basic rule may be like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p TCP --dport 80 -s 192.168.1.7 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1234
```

Taking every traffic coming into port `80`, it redirects whatever is from `192.168.1.7` to port `1234`, leaving the rest intact.

Note [`iptables` operates on a first-match basis](https://serverfault.com/q/367085), so you may want to do

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING …
```

instead.

For various ways to specify multiple possible source addresses, see answers to this question: [*`iptables` multiple source IPs*](https://serverfault.com/q/6989).

But if "with only port 80 open" means you have `iptables -A INPUT …` rules that only allow port 80, I expect the above alone won't work. This is because `nat/PREROUTING` works first. In this case you should also unblock the other port.

Comment: So, if I understood this correctly it redirects only traffic from 192.168.1.7 to port 1234 leaving the rest to 80?

Comment: @Phate Yes. My answer is now expanded.

Comment: It seems to be working but something strange happens: if I do iptables -L to list my rules I can't see the one entered...but it works for sure so it has to be there! I need this in order, in case, to delete it later

Comment: @Phate I believe `iptables -L` is equivalent to `iptables -t filter -L`. You need `iptables -t nat -L`.